# I can't install any packages on Ubuntu Studio 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt

When I try to install a package in terminal it shows something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get vlc 
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
E: Invalid operation vlc
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try the following command lines, `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and  `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: In addition to using the correct command to install, you should also run `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist` to get rid of the first error

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to install vlc, but missing the `install` in the command line.

The correct way of installing a package using apt-get is:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

In your case when the package is vlc:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

According to [VLC site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

You should execute the below two commands in order to install vlc:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```